# Change UIImage in runtime affect in missing constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, ios9, ios-autolayout

I'm with iOS 9 (Swift) showing a set of eight imageViews in a View and I've added contraints to set the position of the imageViews.

Each ImageView loads an image from assets file that has been manually set to each one in the story board.

All working fine, now I want to set random asset in runtime to the imageViews...

```
var images = ["T","B","J","R","R2","I","M","RL"]
var randomImages = images
var indexCount = UInt32(images.count)

for imageView in TopImages{
    let index:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(indexCount))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: randomImages[index])
    randomImages.removeAtIndex(index)
    indexCount -= 1
}
```

When this code run, the imageViews are in different positions than I've designed in story board... seems that when I set programatically ImageView.image = UIImage(...) I'm missing constraints.

Is possible to change the asset name in run time without doing a new instance of UIImage? If it's not possible... Anyone knows any workaround to achieve my goal of loading random images programatically that are added and positioned previously to the story board?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you show us your storyboard and autolayout constraints?

Comment: How are you initializing the UIImage views?

Comment: No, I'm not initializing imageView in code. The only code that affect on runtime to the image views in that fragment shown in the post. If I comment this line: imageView.image = UIImage(named: randomImages[index]) images are properly positioned...

Answer (score 0):

Auto layout uses the intrinsicContentSize of each view in combination with the added constraints to calculate the layout. You can change image in an imageView at runtime but you need to call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize on each UIImageView afterwards and then as a final step after the loop call layoutIfNeeded on the containing view to get everything to be laid again taking the new changes into consideration.